# How to use getExecutionHistory from aws java sdk to check status of a step function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, aws-java-sdk

I am new to aws and doing a PoC around aws lambda and step function.
So my problem statement is:
A http request comes to API gateway which triggers a lambda function and through that lambda I am trigerring a step function something like
*awsStepFunction.startExecution(executionRequest)*

Now, since this is asynchronous in nature it just triggers step function and returns response but
I want to return a response from lambda only when the execution of lambda is completed or failed.

I am using *getExecutionHistory* recursively to get the response of execution but that effects my execution time and also when doing load testing getting *Throttling exception saying rate exceeded*

```java
ExecutionResult result = awsStepFunction.startExecution(executionRequest);
getHistory(awsStepFunction, result);

private void getHistory(awsStepFunction, result){

List<HistoryEvents> list = GetExecutionHistory(request).getEvents;

while(true) {
If(list.get(0).getId == 71 || list.get(0).getStatus.equals("ExecutionFailed")){
    return;
} else {
   Thread.sleep(1000);
  getHistory(awsStepFuncrion,result);
}
return;
}
}
```

71 is the final id of the event confirming that execution has succeeded.

But here when multiple requests are triggered getting error 400 **Throttling exception rate exceeded** in cloudwatch logs and hence getting a http response of **502 bad gateway**

[This is the error screenshot that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csZWA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get response from Lambda or you want to know the response from Step function ?
Lambda will start the step function an return that's it .
In that case you will not want to get response from Lambda .
Where do you want to get response API gateway ? Amazon API has 29 sec time out .

so it comes down to one option to get the response back from Step function .
What you can do is to run step function.
Let it take its own time and when finished create a trigger .

You can have a Event bridge [Event Bridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-events.html) on SUCCEEDED,FAILED,TIMED_OUT and on ABORTED.
Target of Event bridge will be another lambda function which can indicate you the status of the step function .

If you want to get the history of step function like input and output in every step function step function you can very well call   getExecutionHistory  in this lambda function .

Comment: So creating EventBridge rule for step function status change will also yield me the duration of run?

Comment: Yes correct @ArchitAgarwal